# converting PHP to vbscript

Tags: php, vbscript, migration

I'm trying to convert some code from PHP to VBScript. I am not sure what the output from the following might be;

```
foreach ($aMembers as $iID => $aInfo) {
    $aItem = array(
        $aInfo['first_name'], $aInfo['last_name'], $aInfo['email'], $aInfo['status'], 'DT_RowId' => $aInfo['id']
    );
    $output['aaData'][] = $aItem;
}
```

I'm assuming this will ouput something like {"first_name":"Joe","Last_name":"Bloggs","email":"jb@somewhere.com","status":"free","DT_RowId":"4"}

I'm not too sure of the PHP syntax

Many thanks
Pete

Comment: no. you have no keys in the array, just values. it'll be `[["Joe","Bloggs", ...],[...],...]`.

Comment: Thanks for this, can you explain the last bit 'DT_RowId' => $aInfo['id'] thought this meant there were keys.

Comment: ah yes, I didn't scroll to the right far enough. that element will have a key of `DT_RowId`, the rest will just have numeric keys, 0, 1,2,etc...